# Connect a dockerized app to a database from a remote machine via a VPN connection

Tags: sql-server, docker, networking, docker-compose

I'm currently working on a small app that has to fetch data from a SQL Server DB and push it on the cloud. It works correctly, but I would like to dockerize it to make its deployment easier.

The database is on a private network and I have to use a VPN connection to access it for development (in red in the diagram below). In production, the app will be on a VM in the database's network.

[image: Diagram]

I'm still confused with Docker networks and the --publish option.
Here is my docker-compose file for now.

```
version: "3.4"

services:
    myapp:
        build: 
          context: .
          network: host
        restart: always
        ports:
            - "128.1.X.Y:1433:1433"
        container_name: myapp
```

But when I connect to the VPN from my machine (remote) and run my image with this configuration, I get this error:

```
driver failed programming external connectivity on endpoint myapp (bbb3cc...):
Error starting userland proxy: listen tcp4 128.1.X.Y:1433: bind: cannot assign requested address
```

Simply "1433:1433" does not work either. The database cannot be accessed. Not really sure about "network: host" either...
Does anyone know what I could be doing wrong?

And another thing I'm wondering is, will the Docker config be the same when I will deploy my container on the VM?

Thank you!

Comment: The items in `ports` are logically `localIpAddress:localPort:containerPort`. These are ports in your container that you want to expose to incoming traffic from the host or from the outside world. `localIpAddress` has to be bound on the Docker host machine itself, so `127.0.0.1` or `::1` for localhost, `0.0.0.0` for all public addresses, or any specific private address or public address bound to the machine. You can't specify the IP address of a remote machine here.

Comment: It seems that you need to use `server=128.1.X.Y` or its equivalent in your app's connection string inside the container.

Comment: Aside... your network team really shouldn't be using 128.1.X.Y addresses for internal network addresses. By doing this they are masking public IP address space and blocking access to public internet resources. As of [RFC 3330](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc3330#section-2) (circa 2002) the 128.0.0.0/16 block (128.0.0.0-128.0.255.255) was still reserved for internal use but even that got released for public use in [RFC 5735](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc5735#appendix-A) (circa 2010). 128.1.0.0/16 has been public IP address space for a very, very long time.

Comment: samdouble, were you able to figure this out? I have the same challenge. Thank you.

Comment: @user1044169 No, sorry. We ended up using another way!